# Issue with jquery scrolling and removing section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a strange issue with jquery scrolling.

Please note that I am editing a template, 100% code credit goes to megakit & keenthemes.com

---

At the bottom of the page, there is a google maps section. I want to remove this, but for some reason when I do, it breaks the scrolling at the top of the page.

HTML - top of the page where scrolling is breaking

```
<a href="#js__scroll-to-section" class="s-scroll-to-section-v1--bc g-margin-
b-15--xs">
<span class="g-font-size-18--xs g-color--white ti-angle-double-down"></span>
<p class="text-uppercase g-color--white g-letter-spacing--3 g-margin-b-0--
xs">Learn More</p>
 </a>
```

HTML - bottom that I want removing

```
<section class="s-google-map">
<div id="js__google-container" class="s-google-container g-height-400--xs">
</div>
</section>
```

JS for scrolling

```
var handleScrollToSection = function() {
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#js__scroll-to-]:not([href=#js__scroll-to-])').on('click', 
function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
&& location.hostname == this.hostname) {
var target = $(this.hash);
target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
if (target.length) {
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: target.offset().top - 90
}, 1000);
return false;
}
}
});
});
}
```

Indentation has gone a bit wrong copying and pasting but looks correct in the code.

Thanks,

Jimmy

Comment: This is the template

Comment: http://www.justfreetemplates.com/web-templates/view/3755-Megakit--Free-Ultimate-Multipurpose-Bootstrap-Site-Template.html